# What is the maximum possible area of a triangle with perimeter 6? Which triangle has this area?

Tags: triangles, area

I started by listing all the possible values of the sides with regard to the Triangle Inequality. To me, there are only 2 possible triangles: 222 and 231. Finding the area of 222 is easy, but how would I find the area of 231?

Comment: A triangle cannot have side lengths $1,2,3$ units, as $3=2+1$, contradicting the triangle inequality (which is *strict* inequality).

Comment: Note: The problem doesn't seem to specify that the sides are integers, so there are infinitely many possible triangles